# How to rename the binding row element with if condition in asp.net data grid

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I am working in asp.net .net framework 4, i have a data grid and it has a column having values 1,2,3 etc, i want to rename them during binding with if condition, for example if value is 1 display YES, if value is 2, display NO, like that...
I know that grid has an event data bound, but i dont know how to change the value of cell on the bases of if condition in this event, please help.

Thanks
Atif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use condition inline in `.aspx`:

   ```
   <%# ((int)Eval("Property")) == 0 ? "No" : "Yes" %>
   ```
2. Use method at codebehind to format value:

   **.aspx**

   ```
   <%# FormatMyValue(Container.DataItem) %>
   ```

   **.cs**

   ```
   public string FormatMyValue(object value)
   {
       return ((MyDataType)value).Property == 0 ? "No" : "Yes";
   }
   ```
3. Using `RowDataBound` event in codebehind (not elegant, but should work):

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.GridView1.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(GridView1_RowDataBound);
   }

   void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           // get date item
           MyDataType item = (MyDataType)e.Row.DataItem;

           // Set value in the necessary cell. You need to specify correct cell index.
           e.Row.Cells[1].Text = item.Property == 0 ? "No" : "Yes"; ;

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I have more than two attributes, and i want it in the event in code behind c# file, not in asp.

Comment: I've updated the sample as you requested. I didn't have a chance ti check it, so probably some corrections needs here.

Comment: What is MyDataType, i cant get it, its giving error and it should give, i changed it to object, but does not work.

Comment: It's your type of data whitch is represents 1 grid row and the collection of this data is bounded to the DataSource. Debug it and take a look what you have in DataItem property